# Transforming Gamma random variable

Tags: transformation

Suppose I want to transform the Gamma variate like this $Y=(X-\text{mean})/SD$, where $X$ is a gamma variate. I know applying this transformation does not necessarily imply that the distribution of $Y$ is standard Normal. Can I use this transformation on say Gamma or any other skewed variables like lognormal, exponential? I need a reference of a good paper or some book reference for this transformation on Gamma, lognormal, or any other skewed variate.

Answer (score 0):

$$\mathbb{P}(Y\leq y) = \mathbb{P}\left(\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}\leq y\right)=\mathbb{P}(X\leq \mu + \sigma y) \; .$$

Any probability statement you can make about $Y$ can be translated into a statement about $X$. You already know everything you need to know.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually I need some research paper or book reference in which the standardized transformation have been used on skewed distribution variates. Please provide some paper or book for citation. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I do not know why you want to transform a gamma density in such way. Usually the standardization transformations are done to get a standard density in order to calculate probabilities using tables.

If $X\sim \text{Gamma}[n;\theta]$ (where $\theta$ is the rate parameter) the standardization is

$$Y=2\theta X$$

so that now $Y\sim \chi_{(2n)}^2$, known distribution and free of $\theta$

Comment: Dear Tommik, thank you for your reply and useful information. I need to transform gamma variate like this to have the mean of transformed variable equal to zero and variance 1, also negative values of Y. I need to do it empirically. I need some research paper or book reference in which the standardized transformation have been used on skewed distribution variates. Please provide some paper or book for citation. Thanks